# ESLint JSDoc error with callback

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, eslint

I'm having trouble with ESLint `valid-jsdoc` check giving me an error with the following.  Am I missing something? I thought I captured everything that the valid-jsdoc check would need for `PageAdminPublication` function (the selector callback was fine [I updated to have the missing stuff as noted by @Jeremy Rajan]

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo' // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

/**
 * @callback selectorToSearchCb
 * @param {object} selector extra stuff
 */

/**
 * Administrative list publication.  This provides access to all the whole collection with pagination.
 * Only allowed if the user is in the admin role.
 *
 * @param {string} publicationName publication name
 * @param {Mongo.Collection} collection mongo collection
 * @param (selectorToSearchCb) selectorToSearch selector to search function. This is used to convert input selectors to the search object for the find().
 * @param {string} fields an array of field names that would be sent for edit and listing.
 * @return {void}
 */
function PagedAdminPublication(publicationName, collection, selectorToSearch, ...fields) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESlint is not going to be able to parse the comment as you have invalid braces around `selectorToSearchCb`. You need to use `{selectorToSearchCb}` and not `(selectorToSearchCb)`

The following works for me:

```
 /**
   * Administrative list publication.  This provides access to all the whole collection with pagination.
   * Only allowed if the user is in the admin role.
   *
   * @param {string} publicationName publication name
   * @param {Mongo.Collection} collection mongo collection
   * @param {selectorToSearchCb} selectorToSearch selector to search function. This is used to convert input selectors to the search object for the find().
   * @param {string} fields an array of field names that would be sent for edit and listing.
   * @return {void}
   */
```

Comment: Doh derped. Thanks.  I don't think this warrants a stack overflow question now :P